# Simple PHP video upload system

Tags: php, post

Below is a php function of my post method. I am not receiving any errors but however it is not uploading into the folder I have assigned to.

I am using a localhost and there are no errors regarding the database!

```
<div id="box">
<form method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    <?php

       if(isset($_FILES['video'])){

        $name = $_FILES['video']['name'];
        $type = explode('.', $name);
        $type = end($type);
        $size = $_FILES['video']['name'];
        $random_name = rand();
        $tmp = $_FILES['video']['tmp_name'];

        if($type != 'mp4' && $type != 'mp4' && $type != 'flv'){
            $message = "Video Format Not Supported!";
        }

        else {
            move_uploaded_file($tmp, 'videos/'.$random_name.'.'.$type);
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO videos VALUES('.' '$name'; 'videos/$random_name.$type')");
            $message = "Successfully Uploaded!";

        }

        echo "$message"; 

       } 
    ?>


    Select Video : <br/>
    <input type='file' name="video" />
    <br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

Comment: What's the output of `print_r($_FILES["video"]["error"]);`?

Comment: watch out, file type can be faked

Comment: Also, `$size = $_FILES['video']['name'];` is probably not what you expect.

Comment: Did you try smaller files? Maybe your Apache does not allow large Uploads. Rename a .txt in .flv and try to upload.

Comment: I am sorry as I am still new to the PHP! I am actually following a video on youtube.

But apparently, his is working...

The problem is that there are nothing changing other then the link of the web page. I also tried uploading other file types like png and it still works the same. 

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SibODOJle6Q&noredirect=1

Comment: Just found the error. I wrote method wrongly!